# Swift Computed properties cannot be used in init?

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to use MultipeerConnectivity framework with Swift. I have following properties:

```
var peerId: MCPeerID?;
let advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser;
let browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser;
var session: MCSession? 
 ....
```

In my init method, I initialize all my stored properties like this:

```
  init() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    let dataToShow = defaults.dataForKey("kPeerID");
        peerId = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataToShow) as? MCPeerID;
    if !peerId {
        peerId = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name);
        let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(peerId);
        defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "kPeerID");
        defaults.synchronize();
    }

    advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerId, discoveryInfo:nil, serviceType: "stc-classroom");
    browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerId, serviceType: "stc-classroom");
    session = MCSession(peer: self.peerId);
    super.init();

    session!.delegate = self;
    advertiser.delegate = self;
    browser.delegate = self;
}
```

Now as you can see there is quite a bit lines of code to assign value to peerId (Apple recommended way), so I thought it would be nice to put that logic in a computed property so I replaced peerId stored property with a computed property and init method like this:

```
 var peerId: MCPeerID {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    let dataToShow = defaults.dataForKey("kPeerID");
    var peer = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataToShow) as? MCPeerID;
    if peer == nil {
        peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name);
        let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(peer);
        defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "kPeerID");
        defaults.synchronize();
    }
    return peer!;
}
```

Now my init method is much cleaner and shorter like this:

```
init() {
    advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerId, discoveryInfo:nil, serviceType: "stc-classroom");
    browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerId, serviceType: "stc-classroom");
    session = MCSession(peer: self.peerId);        
    super.init();

    session!.delegate = self;
    advertiser.delegate = self;
    browser.delegate = self;
}
```

But now compiler complains as I am trying to access self while accessing peerId in browser/advertiser/session initialization. I understand in Swift all the properties must be initialized before we can use them and self is called implicitly and hence the error. But apparently that means I can't call computed properties in the init method, so I want to know if there is any better way of implementing what I am trying to do or not? I understand that I can create stored properties for every computed property and treat it as an iVar but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution either.

I would really appreciate your help regarding this guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift book doesn't address initialization & computed properties directly, but it has relevant information in the section about inheritance and initialization:

> **Two-Phase Initialization**
>      Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first phase, each stored property is
>   assigned an initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the
>   initial state for every stored property has been determined, the
>   second phase begins, and each class is given the opportunity to
>   customize its stored properties further before the new instance is
>   considered ready for use.

Basically, you need to assign an initial value to all of your non-Optional stored properties (looks like `advertiser` and `browser`) before you can call any methods or access any computed properties. You might instead want to initialize `peerId` with a closure, [using this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_296):

```
var peerId: MCPeerID = {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let dataToShow = defaults.dataForKey("kPeerID")
    var peer = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataToShow) as? MCPeerID
    if peer == nil {
        peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
        let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(peer)
        defaults.setObject(data, forKey: "kPeerID")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
    return peer!
}()
```