# How to set default IBInspectable value for a computed property in Xcode's Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, default-value, ibinspectable

I have a custom `UIView` class which has a `UILabel` as a subview. I want to set the font size of the label in the Interface Builder so I made a computed property `fontSize` that gets and sets the `UILabel` font's point size.

```
@IBDesignable class UIMongolLabel: UIView {

    private let view = UILabel()

    let mongolFontName = "ChimeeWhiteMirrored" // font is always the same

    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let font = view.font {
                return font.pointSize
            } else {
                return 0.0
            }
        }
        set {
            view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: newValue)
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

This works fine if the user sets a value for the Font Size:

[image]

But if the user just adds a new custom view, the Font Size is blank.

[image]

[The answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425644/swift-default-initializer-for-computed-property) say that it doesn't make sense to have a default for a computed property in Swift, but what if I want a default for the Interface Builder? I would like it to say "17" or something. What should I do?

Comment: Since the computed value is based on view.font, can't you just set that to what you want the default fontSize to be?

Comment: Yes, I will probable end up doing this. The problem is that the user can't see what it is when building things in the storyboard. What I would like is for that value to be displayed in the IB.