# Why can I call my function in other functions' bodies but not in the class itself?

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class GameController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var gameImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var softButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var notButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
var timer = NSTimer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.gameImage.image = UIImage(named: "king1")

}

//choose random image and set as game image
func randomGameImage() -> String {

    //these arrays hold the image names
    let kingArray = ["king1", "king2", "king3"]
    let notArray = ["not1", "not2", "not3"]

    //this number decides which array to pull from
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

    //this number picks what image from the array
    let imageNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

    //holds the name of the image
    var gameImageString:String

    //sets image name
    if randomNumber >= 1 {

        gameImageString = kingArray[imageNumber]

    }else{

        gameImageString = notArray[imageNumber]

    }

    //sets image
    self.gameImage.image = UIImage(named: gameImageString)

    //returns name of image
    return gameImageString
}

var bool = true
var score = 0;
var imageShowing:String = randomGameImage()//"king"
```

(use of instance method 'randomGameImage' on type 'GameController'; did you mean to use value of type 'GameController' instead?)

```
@IBAction func kingTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if imageShowing.rangeOfString("king") != nil {
        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = String(score)
        imageShowing = randomGameImage()

    }else{
        performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOver", sender: bool)

    }
}

@IBAction func notTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if imageShowing.rangeOfString("not") != nil {
        score += 1
        scoreLabel.text = String(score)
        imageShowing = randomGameImage()

    }else{
        performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOver", sender: bool)

    }
}



}
```

Can someone please tell me why I can call the randomGameImage method in other methods but not outside of the methods. Sorry I am a programming noob.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the same as this:
[Swift Computed properties cannot be used in init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940855/swift-computed-properties-cannot-be-used-in-init/24941114#24941114)

In Swift's two-phase initialization, you cannot access `self` until finishing phase-1. And assigning a default value to a property occurs at the very first stage of phase-1, before calling `init`. Thus, you cannot use `self` in a default value expression of a stored property, which means you cannot call instance methods nor you cannot use other instance properties.

You can use class methods or global functions as an initial value.

Comment: I don't have a broad knowledge of programming terminology. If you don't mind could you explain... Could I make randomGameImage a class method? This seems kind of ridiculous how am I supposed to use the function/method I wrote?

Comment: Your `randomGameImage()` is accessing an instance property `self.gameImage` which may not be initialized yet. So, removing the line and you can make it a class method. Just prefix `class` before `func randomGameImage()`. But you need to modify some other parts.

Comment: So even if the method doesn't include an instance property you get the same error if the parameter is an instance property, correct?

Comment: Right, it's included in "some other parts".